# Get the node clicked

Tags: c#, cursor, mouse-position

I have the code in C# for getting node clicked:

```
public Node ChartMouseDownFindNode(Graphics graphics, Font font, Point mousePosition)
{
    this.mousePosition = Cursor.Position;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 124, 176, 34), 2);
    foreach (Node node in Nodes)
    {
       Size nodeSize = node.GetNodeSize(graphics, font);
       if (node.Position.X < mousePosition.X + Math.Abs(mousePosition.X) && node.Position.X + nodeSize.Width > mousePosition.X + Math.Abs(mousePosition.X))
            if (node.Position.Y < mousePosition.Y + Math.Abs(mousePosition.Y) && node.Position.Y + nodeSize.Height > mousePosition.Y + Math.Abs(mousePosition.Y))


                return node;
        MessageBox.Show("clicked");



    }
    return null;
}
```

It does not work. I guess there is something wrong with the cursor. My idea is to compare node's position with mouse's position.
THanks a lot!

Comment: what's a Node in your sample?

Comment: Why are you adding the mouseposition and the absolute of the mouseposition? This is either twice the position or 0.

Comment: I use graphics to draw node, it's rectangle type. The node class contains contents of node, like id, name.

Comment: @RalZarek, sorry, I do not understand your question very well.

Comment: @user1490952 I mean the mousePosition.X + Math.Abs(mousePosition.X) parts, you end up with 2 * mousePosition.X if it is positive and 0 if it is negative. I was asking about the reason for that.

Comment: @RalZarek, thanks for explanation. That part was written by my friend. SO....

Comment: @user1490952 You're comparing a x/y-coordinate with a x/y-coordinate times 2, which looks like it could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code of your friend is wrong. These if statements will be better.

```
if (node.Position.X < mousePosition.X && node.Position.X + nodeSize.Width > mousePosition.X)
    if (node.Position.Y < mousePosition.Y && node.Position.Y + nodeSize.Height > mousePosition.Y)
```

And before this statements, you may need to match position coordinates. Cursor.Position is in screen space coordinate but nodes might be in client space coordinate, I guess. This code will work.

```
mousePosition = PointToClient(mousePosition);
```